# Symfony Node JS Check if user is authenticated

Tags: node.js, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

I'm creating a project, but I'm running into a problem. In my project, after user logs in he will be redirected to my dashboard. When the user is logged in, there will be an attempt to connect to my node server. But how can I authenticate the user, so that non-authenticated user cannot acces the server? What should I pass to the server? I'm using the FOSUserBundle.

Comment: Have you looked at [passport](http://passportjs.org/)?

Comment: No, but could you give me an idea in how to integrate it into Symfony? I'm new in authentication.

Comment: Passwort is a node component i.e. it's hosted by your Node server. I got the impression from your question that you are looking for *node* authentication, not PHP - if so passport is the de facto standard.

Comment: The user is already logged in when it comes on my dashboard, and then a connection with Node.JS is etablished. How can I check with Node so that not every random person can connect with the server, only authenticated people?